# Get total of each record in separate column in tablix in SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I had binded the data in tablix, With group by as "subject name" as separate column. all the subjects will be dynamic. The report has been generated fine. But now I wants to add the "Total" column which should display the sum of all dynamic grouped subject columns.

I Created the new add total column with expression as "=Sum(Fields!Marks.Value)"

But I got the column as "#error".

Comment: Looks like you might just need to convert the `Marks` field.  Try `=Sum(CInt(Fields!Marks.Value))`

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the column group called SubjectName2 and choosing 'add total' -> 'after'?

Comment: Steve is most likely correct - but center those Class and Section fields while your fixing the expression. And why is SOCIAL STUDIES capitalized. :o

Comment: @Steve-o169 Thanks it worked with conversion.